# How to populate drop-down list with database values in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am very new to CakePHP. Could you please explain me the steps needed to populate a select drop-down with values from the database. Please also suggest me some links to the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a find in the db and then set the variable via `$this->set(yourvariable)` in the controller.

In the view you use the "yourvariable" in the select tag

[Fill select 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353680/belongsto-problem-in-cakephp-and-html-select-i-cant-understand-how-to-do-that)

[Fill select 2](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/KiltOtter/2007/04/21/filling-a-select-tag)

[Fill select 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188733/automagic-select-box-not-populating-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 4):

Simple, if it's a related model in your controller you pass 'list' into the find(); an cake will make an id => value array for you, and the form helper will know exactly what to do with it.

For example say you want to get the list of categories for a product model, this is in your contoller:

```
$categories = $this->Product->Categories->find('list');
$this->set(compact('categories'));
```

Then in your view using the form helper, simply create the select element how you normally would any input:

```
$form->input('category_id');
```

The form helper will automatically load the $categories variable we set with $this->set().

Answer (score 2):

There is a cakeish way to do it with very less effort

```
 $this->set('arrMain',$this->Post->find('list',
                                            array(
                                                'fields'=>array('id','title')
                                                )));
```

Will give output as ==>

```
<select id="UserAge" name="data[User][Age]">
<option value="1">The title</option>
<option value="2">A title once again</option>
<option value="3">Title strikes back</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the controller you do:

```
$this->loadModel('MyModel'); //if it's not already loaded
$options = $this->MyModel->find('all'); //or whatever conditions you want
$this->set('options',$options);
```

and in the view

```
<select...>
  <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option['MyModel']['id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['MyModel']['field']; ?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: doesnt look very cakeish^^ i prefer using the form helper

Comment: $model->find('list') is your friend.

Comment: Yes.. but find list is slower :)

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

*in your controller Class*

```
$categories = $this->Articles->find('list')->select(['id', 'title'])->toArray();

$this->set(compact('categories')); // pass result dataset to the view
```

*In Your view file*

```
<?php echo $this->Form->select('articles_categories_id', $categories); ?>
```

> Reading Source
>   http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html