# Country List Dropdown in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I want to ask how to add country list dropdown in cakephp? I have country table in the database.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a field in your form like so:

```
$this->Form->input('country_id');
```

right?

Then just pass the countries down from the controller:

```
$countries = $this->ModelName->Country->find('list');
$this->set(compact('countries'));
```

Since your Model should be connected ("related") to Country via BelongsTo relation.

This is really just absolute cakephp basics. Please try the tutorial and read the documentation careful. This is all covered there. Also, I highly recommend that you bake your code - this way you can learn a lot more, as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
//controller
$this->set('data', $this->Model->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Model.id', 'Model.name')
)));
//veiw
echo $form->input('Model.field',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at -> 
[How to populate drop-down list with database values in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058793/how-to-populate-drop-down-list-with-database-values-in-cakephp)

It's also useful if you find yourself using relations.