# CakePHP format find('all') to ('list') in view?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way to format the $this->find('all') array into the $this->find('list') in the view? The reason I ask is so that I can pass that new array into the form helper options and then use the $this->find('all') array to build some additional things I need?

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [School] => Array ( [id] => 0 [name] => Nature [address] => 112 Main [max_students] => 25 [application_level] => 5 ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [School] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Math [address] => 112 Smith [max_students] => 25 [application_level] => 0 ) ) 
[2] => Array ( [School] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Art [address] => 112 Lane [max_students] => 25 [application_level] => 0 ) ) 
)
```

So this is the array I get when I do a find('all'). I want to build the array so it looks like:

```
Array (
[0] => 'Nature'
[1] => 'Math'
[2] => 'Art'
)
```

This is usually done by the $this->find('list') function. Though the reason I want the whole array is because I need to add the application_level into $this->Form->input() function. This is because I need to add the option of class with the application level attached so I show only the shows with the application level based on the previous selection.

EDIT: Can't I just do $this->find('list', [insert parameters here?]);? I just don't understand how you set up the additional parameters?

Comment: you could run the query twice, or you could run your own loop after the `all` query and populate your own list

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate drop-down list with database values in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058793/how-to-populate-drop-down-list-with-database-values-in-cakephp)

Comment: I've added the question based on reading through the CakePHP documentation.

Comment: @pmac89 Are you populating a radio button? a select input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your query isn't overly complicated and isn't going to return a excessive number of results, just run it twice (once for find all and once for find list).

Find all, list, first, whatever are all the same in terms of the paramaters you pass in. E.g.:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'field' => 500,
        'status' => 'Confirmed'
    ),
    'order' => 'id ASC'
));
```

... you literally replace `all` with `list`. In your case, probably easiest to do it twice, once for each. Like this:

```
$parameters = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'field' => 500,
        'status' => 'Confirmed'
    ),
    'order' => 'id ASC'
);

$alldata = $this->Model->find('all', $parameters);
$listdata = $this->Model->find('list', $parameters);
```

Otherwise, you can loop through it and populate your own list:

```
$list = array();

foreach($findall as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $list[$id] = $name;
}

$this->set('listdata', $list);
```

Short answer to your question is that there's no quick, easy way to select `all` **and** `list` from the same query, but you can re use your parameters (conditions, order etc) by passing them in as predefined arrays, or populate your own list.

Comment: but the important question is, what do you need to do in the view with that data? depending on what the asker need this process is not needed

Comment: The important question is what he asked us: `Is there a way to format the $this->find('all') array into the $this->find('list') in the view?`

Comment: I don't see the point in making a find('list') and then rework the result to make it look as the result of a find('all'), that is the reason I am asking @pmac89 what is he/she trying to accomplish in the view, maybe there is something more efficient that can be done.

Comment: No, I'm going from the find('all') array to the find('list') because I still need information from the find('all').

Comment: @pmac89 I am trying to help you here, What do you need to do in the view with that data?

Comment: One, I'm not downvoting you. Though I think the above solves my problem. I'm just trying to figure it out to my problem. Basically, I'm doing a find('all') because I need the application_level but I need to turn the find('all') array into one that looks like the find('list') array. Then in the options for the form helper input I need to make the 'class' => 'school_options'.$schools['application_level']

Answer (score 5):

An alternative answer to creating the results formatted like find('list') from results from find('all') using CakePHP's hash utility:

```
//where $data is the result of find all
App::uses('Hash', 'Utility');
$ids = Hash::format($data, array('{n}.Model.id'), '{0}'); //ids in an array.
$names = Hash::format($data, array('{n}.Model.name'), '{0}'); //names in an array
$dataAsList = array_combine($ids, $names);
```

Comment: didn't have idea regarding the Hash::format. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

To improve on kai's answer. The Hash class has a method called combine that can do what you're trying to do in only one line

```
$list = Hash::combine($data,'{n}.Model.id','{n}.Model.name');
```

the `$list` will be a flat array like data from `find('list')`;

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3 & 4 you can do the following:

```
$tags = $this->tags->find()->all();
$tagOptions = $tags->combine('id', 'name');
```

See:

- [Using Collections to build options](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls) from the CakePHP manual.