# how to load category names in drop down list

Tags: php, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I want to load only main categories(not sub-categories) name in drop down list. i have tried enough but could not succeed. There are numbers of answer on this site and I tried to solve my problem in that way but can't. The category table is given below, it is same as on cakephp docs in Tree.

### categories table attribute

### id | parent_id | lft| rght |name |

i tried these techniques given on following links
[How to populate drop-down list with database values in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058793/how-to-populate-drop-down-list-with-database-values-in-cakephp)

full code of controller to create category is given below.

```
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Category->create();
            if ($this->Category->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Category has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add Category.'));
        }
        else 
          $categories = $this->Category->find('list');
          $this->set(compact('categories'));
           return $this; 
      }
```

code of category.ctp is

```
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('Category'); ?>
        <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Category'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php
                $form->input('id');
        //      echo $this->Form->input('id');
                echo $this->Form->input('name');

        ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
        </div>
```

now please suggest me solution to load data in drop down list.

Comment: For future questions, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: ok,I will do, cakephp verion is 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick to the conventions and everything's going to be ok. I assume you need the list in your add form to select the parent category (your intent btw is something that you should clarify in your question).

With trees you want to order by `lft`, so if you use `find('list')` you'll have to pass that in the `order` option, and in order to retrieve only the top-level categories you'll have to pass in a condition that matches all categories where `parent_id` is `null` (or the ID of a parent category whichs sub-categories are your "main" categories).

**Controller**

```
$parents = $this->Category->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Category.parent_id' => null
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'Category.lft' => 'asc'
    )
));
$this->set('parents', $parents);
```

**View**

```
echo $this->Form->input('parent_id');
```

For more information see

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements**

Comment: thanks for this , but actually i want to select only main categories first time when user will select main category then sub categories will be shown in other drop down list. so please guide me for this .

Comment: @user3623305 That's an entirely different problem, and has nothing to do with your intial question as it stands. Please read **http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking**

Comment: off course my first question is different to my above comment, in first question i was asking to display categories but in your solution all categories and sub categories are being displayed. that's why i mention my point in above comment. so just guide me to display only main categories in drop down menu as i mention ed in first line of my question.

Comment: @user3623305 Your question only says "categories", a "sub-category" is a "category" too. You should update your question to clarify the actual problem so that is useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

you can put in controller
       $this->loadModel('Category');
       $categories = $this->Category->find('list');
       $this->set('categories',$categories));

put code of category.ctp is

```
           <?php if(isset($categories )){
             foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
                  $id= $value['Category']['id'];
                  $options[$id]=$value['Category']['name'];                   
              }
           } 
           echo $this->Form->select('Category.id', $options,array('class'=>'select2','data-  placeholder'=>'Choose a category','empty'=>''));
             ?>
```

It will work.

Comment: now facing this error after using your code. Call to a member function input() on a non-object

Comment: in code you mentioned for controller , i think $categories is without quotes , is it? i used it without quotes. now error is ERROR: Cannot use string offset as an array , it is on line 3 which is                                                      $id= $value['Category']['id'];